# pgAdmin 4 Database lost after filed start-up - how do I recover the connection?

Tags: pgadmin

After a few months away from pgAdmin 4, I attempted to open the program - first time, it failed, second time it started up - but the database, called 'athome4' was missing.

[image: pgadmin 4 grab]

I checked in QGIS and the database and files still exist.

[image]

So I would like to know how I can recover the connection to pgAdmin 4 so I can work with this database again.

I simple step by step explanation would be best.

I am very concerned that if I start work on a new project that this may happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake - the connection was fine, my missing 'database' was hiding under 'Schemas'.

[image]